# How to get a pseudoelement after the label of a paper-icon-button

Tags: css, material-design, paper-elements, core-elements

I have the following .html code

```dart
  <paper-icon-button
    id = 'add-btn'
    label = 'NAME'
    icon = 'social:person'
    on-click = '{{ toggle }}'
    ></paper-icon-button>
```

In my style.css...

```dart
          /deep/ paper-icon-button[label]::after {
          content: " *";
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 150%;
          color: red;
        }
```

However, the result is not what is desired. The red * is placed below the label, if ::after is used, the red * is placed above the label.

Is there a tweak to allow the * to be placed immediately after the label?

If this is impossible currently, is there a best practice for paper-elements to suggest to the user that this paper-icon-button is required?

Although this link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

was informative it did not help in terms of a solution.

Please see the screenshot for what the actual and desired result should be like.[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your button and mark the position where the `*` should be placed.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/472q0e81/ ?

Comment: @ Vitorino Fernandes | Thanks but it will not work as you suggest with paper-elements.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer | screenshot added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is a block element, this is the reason why the `*` is shown in the next line. This css places the `*` inside the button and I think this is what you want.

```css
  * /deep/ paper-icon-button[label]::shadow div#content > span::after {
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
  }
```

It selects all `paper-icon-buttons` that have a `label` attribute and then in the shadow DOM of the `paper-icon-button` the `div` with id `content` and adds the  `*` after the divs child `span` element which is the label.

#### update

```dart
<paper-icon-button
  id = 'add-btn'
  label = 'NAME'
  required
  icon = 'social:person'
  on-click = '{{ toggle }}'
></paper-icon-button>
```

```css
  * /deep/ paper-icon-button[label][required]::shadow div#content > span::after {
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
  }
```

This way only `paper-icon-buttons` that have a `required` attribute get the `*`.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. It works. Two questions 1) Please point me with a link to some material where I can understand these complex css shadow dom. 2) Is there some means of preventing a specific paper-icon-button label from not being selected or some means of selecting specific paper-icon-buttons using the answer above.

Comment: I just use the `inspect element` context menu in the browser and look how the HTML looks like. `/deep/` goes through arbitrary levels of `shadowRoot`, `::shadow` just goes into the shadow DOM of the selected element. I read only https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html and https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html. You can just apply a required attribute and use it in the selector (I'll update my answer).

Comment: I have to admit that I read these two docs **many times** ;-) To `complex`: The `div#content` part might not be necessary but the `span` that is the label has no way to address it directly (no id, class, attribute) therefore I specified its parent in the selector to ensure the `*` is not added to other spans that might be somewhere inside the button.

Comment: Thats OK! I will have to do the same to get a deeper understanding since I find myself using this tool repeatedly. Any suggestion on my two questions in my previous comments? Thanks

Comment: I thought I addressed all your questions, which one did I miss? I added an additional comment to the updated answer.

Comment: Yes you did. I missed it in your second comment above. Thanks. I missed it it your updated comment.

Comment: You can also use `class` if you prefer it over `attribute` you have to change `[required]` with `.required` to achieve this.